# Custom config location and config name on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to customize Spring Boot config location and config name using `spring.config.name` and `spring.config.location` properties as I've saw on [Spring Boot reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)

I've created an [Spring Boot basic application](https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-application-different-config-location) to test it.

I'm able to customize it using OS environment variable like `export SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=custom` and/or `export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=classpath:/custom/location.properties`. That works fine!

But I want to know, if it's possible to define `spring.config.name=custom` on default `application.properties` and then create a `custom.properties` file where I'll be able to define all application configuration properties.

> I've checked it, and seems that it's not working defining `spring.config.name` property on `application.properties`... but I want to know if this is a valid way to do it before to create an issue on gitHub.

Regards,

Comment: Spring Boot documentation has been updated to include my suggestions on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/a87a1f053f7109fc649498c91cfeaa86c2cac38b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> spring.config.location ***environment property*** (comma-separated list of
>   directory locations, or file paths)

Moreover, code in [ConfigFileApplicationListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.java#L540) shows that if there if no environment property, processing fallbacks to:

```
DEFAULT_SEARCH_LOCATIONS = "classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/";
```

And for the name:

```
DEFAULT_NAMES = "application";
```

So it is normal that what you are doing is not working.

Comment: Sure, environment variables are the right way to do it... as you could see on `README.adoc` file of my sample application, I'm using environment variables... but I want to know if there's some way to define it on `application.properties` file. If you read [Spring Boot - Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) section, you could see that `spring.config.name` and `spring.config.location` appears, so they could be added to `application.properties` file.. isn't it?

Comment: following your link, I found out the spring code managing these properties. Please see my answer update.

Comment: Ok. so... if `spring.config.name` and `spring.config.location` properties only are available on *environment*... maybe Spring Boot reference guide needs an update to prevent confusions with these properties... isn't it?

Comment: You are right. Even if it says that the list is just informative, the documentation can be confusing.

Comment: Exactly.. I've just create an [issue on Spring Boot gitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4838) to discuss about if is necessary to update Spring Boot reference guide or if it's possible to detect `spring.config.*` properties on default locations too... Regards and thanks for the answers.

Comment: Spring Boot documentation has been updated to include my suggestions on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/a87a1f053f7109fc649498c91cfeaa86c2cac38b